# Sort voluminous file text by date using python

Tags: python, sorting, datetime

I'm  new with python and I have to sort by date a voluminous file text with lot of line like these:

```
   CCC!LL!EEEE!EW050034!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1 
   CCC!LL!EEEE!GH676589!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1
   CCC!LL!EEEE!IJ6758004!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1
```

Can someone help me please ?

Thank you all !

Comment: Show us your code and what you have tried so far so we can start from that.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you sure that the date will be immediately after the fourth exclamation point in each line and that the date will be in the format YYYY-MM-DD ? Do you also need to sort on the time? Do you know any other formatting details about each line in the file? Just how "voluminous" is the file? Will it all fit in RAM at once?

Comment: Yes the date will alwayd be immediatly after the fourth exclamation point in each line in that format. the file is about 893 Mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the *nix [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) program? in raw terms, it'll probably be faster than most Python scripts.

Use `-t \!` to specify that columns are separated by a `!` char, `-k n` to specify the field, where `n` is the field number, and `-o outputfile` if you want to output the result to a new file.
Example:

```
sort -t \! -k 5 -o sorted.txt input.txt
```

Will sort `input.txt` on its 5th field, and output the result to `sorted.txt`

Comment: @ibia75: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to convert the time to timestamp then sort.
first convert the date to list.

```
rawData = '''CCC!LL!EEEE!EW050034!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1 
   CCC!LL!EEEE!GH676589!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1
   CCC!LL!EEEE!IJ6758004!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1'''
a = rawData.split('\n')
>>> import dateutil.parser,time
>>> sorted(a,key= lambda line:time.mktime(dateutil.parser.parse(line.split('!')[4]).timetuple()))
['CCC!LL!EEEE!EW050034!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1 ', '   CCC!LL!EEEE!GH676589!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1', '   CCC!LL!EEEE!IJ6758004!2016-04-01T04:39:54.000Z!7!1!1!1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into regular expression module, I've used it a couple of times and it looks lretty simple to do what you want with this module
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html Here is the docs but try googling for regular expression python examples to make it more clear, good luck.